# What are the technical specs of the Nordic NRF 31512?

Tags: integrated-circuit, semiconductors, system-on-chip

can someone tell me what chip this is and where I can find the datasheet? Or at least if this is a custom fabrication, what chip from Nordic is it based off of? I've search high and low on the Internet and just can't seem to find any details on this tiny chip.

[image]

Comment: It's an old chip, not recommended for new designs, Nordic seem to be hiding most legacy info but there is a response here, [https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/116000/how-to-program-nrf31512/](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/116000/how-to-program-nrf31512/)

Comment: I understand, but I am looking for some technical specs for the chip.